# Azure : VM interference

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

In Azure, VMs from different services might be co located on the same physical host. Is there any possibility that one might interfere to the other? In other words, is there a guarantee for isolation between vms in all aspects (cpu, io, networking)?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the statement "VMs from different services might be co located on the same physical host"? What exactly do you mean by the question "is there a guarantee for isolation between vms in all aspects"? Are you asking if VM's belonging to different customers run on the same host?

Comment: Yes, I mean, is there a guarantee that VMs, belonging to different customers, that run on the same host, will not interfere to one another

Answer (score 1):

Unless you talk of resource competition (IO, networking, CPU - this is a limited ressource on the host) then isolation is the whole reson we DO virtualization. It would be useless without.

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows Azure Trust Center](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/trust-center/security/) has a bunch of information to address the specific concerns. Section Two of the [Windows Azure Security Overview whitepaper](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9740388&clcid=0x409) might be particularly useful. Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to [sf]. We generally prefer answers which are complete and self-contained; answers consisting only of links should be avoided. Please edit your post so that it actually answers the question.